# Spring, how to return XML response from string without additional converters?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a @RestController with multiple methods like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getSomething", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<SomeClassXml> getSomething() {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok(something);
}
```

Response goes through MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter and i have response containing XML.

But in one of methods i am obtaining String with already prepared XML content from 3rd party source. 
If i'm using something like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getXmlPreparedEarlier", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getXmlPreparedEarlier() {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok(stringWithXml);
}
```

i have broken response:

```
<String>
    &lt;tag>xml content&lt;/tag>
</String>
```

Is there a way to return xml content as is? I don't need to serialize/convert/sanitize it. Response has to keep content type "application/xml" and it would be nice to save method's "produces" annotation because it is also used by swagger doc generator.

Comment: `public String getXmlPreparedEarlier() { return stringWithXml; }`, or, if that does not work, `@ResponseBody public String getXmlPreparedEarlier() { return stringWithXml; }`?

Comment: Are you sure that the string you obtain from the external source is not already broken? Do you have any custom configuration for your message converters? Which Spring Boot version are you using? I've tried to reproduce your issue on 2.0.2, but it works for me.

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/lpb/stackoverflow-50717997.

Comment: @korolar i'm sure about string, i checked value before return with debugger. Yes, as i mentioned - i do have a converter - `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` with supported media type `MediaType("application", "xml")` so result i have with string is kind of expected. I use this converter to convert all other responses from other methods of controller, they all return objects with Jackson XML annotations. The problem i have - i don't know how write/annotate method which will return string with prepared xml. My knowledge of spring and it's configurations is poor.

Comment: Ok, i guess i found the solution. I just had to add another converter `StringHttpMessageConverter` with same supported media type `mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);` @manish @korolar thank you both for your help!

Comment: Above gitlab.com/lpb/stackoverflow-50717997. link is very use full for me thanks Korolar